# react-chartjs-2 time adapters, "time" is not a registered scale

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

i tried to import the time adapters to my ReactJS project but look like it's not working. I wasn't able to configure Chart.js to work with 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns'. My code is below.

I imported them like this:

```js
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from "chart.js";
import "chartjs-adapter-date-fns";
import { Bubble } from "react-chartjs-2";

ChartJS.register(LinearScale, PointElement, Tooltip, Legend);
```

The configurations of the Chart:

```js
  const data = {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "TheDataset1",
        data: theDataArray1,
        backgroundColor: "#782D2D",
      },
    ],

const options = {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: "time",
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
      },
    },
  };
```

This is how I deployed to ReactDOM:

```js
<Bubble options={options} data={data} />
```

When I remove **time** type from options the error is goes away and I see the milliseconds epoch in X axis. And when I add the **time type** console.log gives this errors and my content is not rendering it self.

```js
>Error 1:
Uncaught Error: "time" is not a registered scale.

>Error2:
he above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(ChartComponent)> component:

>Error3:
Uncaught Error: "time" is not a registered scale.
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Fixed with importing "TimeScale" from Chart.js module. Then added TimeScale argument to Chart.register function. At the end:

```
import {Chart, LinearScale, PointElement, Tooltip, Legend, TimeScale} from "chart.js"; 

ChartJS.register(LinearScale, PointElement, Tooltip, Legend, TimeScale);
```

These fixed everything.